# Two(sometimes 3) leading definitions of Darknet/Deep web nomenclature?

Tags: darknet, clear-net

In my experience there seems to different leading definitions of darknet/deep web. The first,

- Deep Web is private places on the clearnet, such as DMs
- Darknet is Tor's network in general

The second,

- Deep Web is considered to be places of the onion network where legal activity takes place
- Darknet is is considered to be places of the onion network where illegal activity takes place
- Obviously none of Tor is optimized for illegal activity, and areas of Tor where legal/illegal activity take place are not technologically different. Just different places in Tor

The third,

- Darknet/Deep web are the same and mean Tor in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These words have no technical meaning and aren't used by the people who actually build these systems, so they have no formal definitions. For example these words are not used by Tor or the research community. They are terms used mostly by the media and are usually used to project privacy tools in a negative way, or by people trying to make these privacy tools sound mysterious. Feel free to use these terms however you want, but it's usually better to use the actual technical names of the systems you're discussing (for example onion services) so that people know what you're talking about.

Comment: So your saying it's more or less slang. I understand. Yes, I have seen too many hooligans use these phrases in ways that make Tor out to be something completely different from what it really is.

Comment: Yeah that's a good way to put it. Whenever someone says "darknet", "dark web", etc, just substitute in Tor / onion services / anonymity depending on the context.